# Bicycle Computer Dead Reckoning

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am creating a device where you can do video game bike racing by putting your bicycle on a trainer and hooking it up to your tablet/phone, which will count the pulses from a reed switch or hall effect sensor and calculate your speed, distance, etc in the same manner as a regular bike computer, and use that to move your avatar in the game world. It's written in Java with libGDX.

I'm stuck trying to get the digital bike to coast to a stop. If you are going a given speed, such that the time between pulses is normally 100ms, then if we check the time delta and it's been 200ms since the last click, we know you can't be going more than half of your former speed, and we should adjust down accordingly every time we update your speed, eventually passing some threshold where we decide you've effectively stopped.

I want the speed to decay along a roughly logarithmic curve so that hopefully I can approximate the speed envelope that your bike would have out on pavement. I also need to be smart about estimating the distance you've traveled since the last click, so that your distance doesn't jump ahead if we suddenly get a click.

How can I accomplish getting the bike to coast to a stop, and how should I go about positioning the bike in the game world with the uncertainty of how far we have to go until the next click? I have scoured the Internet looking for examples of code for a bicycle computer, and haven't found any yet, let alone any that have the added restriction that they need to be able to render their current position in the game world.

Here's the code:

The click function runs every time we get another pulse from the bike sensor:

```
public void click() {
  currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  int delta = (int) (currentTime - lastClick);

  // If we have less than N samples, just add it to the list.
  // Otherwise pop one off and fill it in with the new value.
  if (samples.size() == SAMPLE_RESOLUTION) {
    samples.remove(0);
  }
  samples.add(delta);
  clicks += 1;
  lastClick = currentTime;
}
```

And the averageSamples function averages the last N samples to smooth out the speed. It's just a simple average right now, but later I intend on making it weighted such that new data is weighted more than old data.

```
public double averageSamples() {
  Integer sum = 0;
  if (!samples.isEmpty()) {
    for (Integer sample : samples) {
      sum += sample;
    }
  return wheelCircumference / (sum.doubleValue() / samples.size());
  }
  return sum.doubleValue();
}
```

And finally, the update function runs every frame of the game, so about once every 60th of a second. It's supposed to calculate your speed and distance, guessing how far you've gone since the last click based on the amount of time that's passed since then:

```
public void update() {
  double newSpeed;
  currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  int delta = (int) (currentTime - lastClick);

  // The below line needs to adjust your speed downward if it's been too long since the last click. We're hoping for a smooth curve on the way to coasting to a stop.
  newSpeed = averageSamples();
  elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

  instSpeed = newSpeed;
  avgSpeed = (avgSpeed + instSpeed) / 2;
  maxSpeed = Math.max(newSpeed,instSpeed);

  /* This line needs to guess how far you've gone since the last click. Right now I'm using this value directly to draw the bike at a certain place in the game world, so we need to do this in a way that if we suddenly get a click, you don't end up jumping forward. */
  distance = (long) (clicks * wheelCircumference);
 }
```

Comment: I think a question would be how slow would the physical wheel need to be moving to know it has stopped. Also consider using a rotary encoder to get a better mapping of the physical wheel to a digital model.

Comment: Also consider using a negative acceleration as 'friction' to slow down your velocity vector as long as the velocity is above zero.

Comment: Are you considering only flat terrain? (going downhill without pedalling shouldn't cause the bicycle to stop: that's a sign that relying only on the pedals sensor is limiting). How many ticks you get from a whole pedal cycle - 2ᴨ? (if one only, I'm afraid the modelled behaviour can't be made natural enough)

Comment: That might be an option, Morrison, but since I already have the hardware for the hall effect sensor version, keeping the current hardware would be preferred.

On my real bicycle the computer displays anything less than 2mph as 0, so that would be a good cutoff for us to know that it has stopped.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: yes, flat terrain only. The idea is that you would plug in on your trainer and race with your friend who lives far away, so inside the game the terrain will all be flat. There's only one hall effect sensor on the bike, and currently only one magnet, so we only get one click per revolution, just like a regular bike computer.  And it doesn't have to perfectly model the wheel, just be as good as the regular bike computer is, so a negative acceleration as Morrison suggested would be acceptable.  It's also an option to add more magnets to the wheel, but that seems overkill.

Comment: @TonySherwood While a single hall sensor would be good as a odometer on a bike, I'm not sure for a game that it would provide enough fidelity of user action to in game action.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I add 12 magnets... One on every third spoke. That would change the code in that it would make us certain of the location down to 1/12 of the wheel circumference, but we'd still be left with the problem of making the bike coast to a stop if we haven't heard from the hall effect sensor in x milliseconds, and if 1/12 of the wheel circumference works out to more than one pixel of game world, we still have the problem of the bike possibly jumping forward if we suddenly have a click. Do you have any code suggestions for those problems?

Comment: @TonySherwood having more probes enables you a higher collection frequency. As such you can average or interpolate your speed using the same number of samples in a shorter time - at 60 cycles per minute, to average with enough precision for a natural behaviour, you'll need 4-5 seconds. With 12 probes... well, you could afford to estimate your average speed every half a second.